# debugging mono asp.net on xsp4 on linux: can't see errors in console, browser or logs

Tags: asp.net, linux, debugging, mono, xsp

I can't seem to be able to debug an asp.net application with either xsp4 or ngingx. The official site says to use: `MONO_OPTIONS=--debug xsp4 --verbose`. And theoretically debugging is enabled, excepting I don't get any info whatsoever about errors. Calling a route results in a "an error occurred" message" and nothing else, while the console from which I started xsp4 doesn't say anything. Haven't found a way to log the debug info.

Some old posts suggests that having no console output is normal, but that the error in the web page should be more detailed: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2005-July/027717.html. The solution proposed there, asp.net tracing, doesn't seem to give me the debug exception. Tested it on Windows. I also tried with mono-fastcgi-server4 and nginx. A stackoverflow answer said enabling debugging is done like this: `export MONO_OPTIONS="--debug" fastcgi-mono-server-4 /applications="/:/srv/www/htdocs/mywebapp" /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000`. Done this, but no debug output. Nor in the console, neither in the log of mono-fastcgi-server or nginx, neither on the actual page.

Now for versions:

I am running
Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:33:52 UTC 
2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-proj
ect.com

```
    TLS:           __thread                                                 
    SIGSEGV:       normal                                                   
    Notifications: epoll                                                    
    Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard                                           
    Disabled:      none                                                     
    Misc:          softdebug                                                
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.                                  
    GC:            sgen
```

`xsp4 --version`

Mono.WebServer2.dll 0.4.0.0
(c) (c) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Classes for embedding an ASP.NET server in your application .NET 4.0.
Debian 7.8 on raspberry pi 2.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have a detailed error page if you set, in your app.config, the value `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in the `<system.web>` element. By default, on Runtime builds, this value is set to something other than Off, hiding technical details to the public.